# Vector space bases without axiom of choice

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice, hamel-basis

I want to find an example of a vector space with no base if we assume that axiom of choice is incorrect. This question might be duplicate so please alert me. Thanks.

Comment: I can't prove it, but I'd be surprised if one could establish a basis for the space of all (real- or complex-valued) sequences without the axiom of choice.

Comment: @DanielFischer DERP.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Nope, COFFEE!

Comment: @DanielFischer [Why no both?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgk-lA12FBk)

Comment: Inspired by the comment of @ZhenLin below: If the axiom of choice is incorrect, the only thing we know is that there exists a setting where it fails. But we don't know which one, which probably makes it impossible to pin down a concrete vector space without a base. So probably, you should reformulate this part to something like "if we cannot invoke the axiom of choice".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proof is not as constructive as one would expect.

I suggest that you take a look at Andreas Blass' paper in which he proved that the existence of bases implies the axiom of choice. From the proof it is easy to construct a counterexample.

The proof idea is to take a family of non-empty sets, and to show that there exists a choice function (not quite exactly, Blass goes through another equivalence first). Assuming the axiom of choice fails, there is a family of non-empty sets which doesn't have a choice function. From this you can construct a counterexample to the principle that Blass is using in his equivalence, and then you can easily construct the vector space which doesn't have a basis.

On the other hand, it is not very hard to construct specific models in which there are specific vector spaces without bases. $\ell_2$ doesn't have a basis in Solovay's model, and generally in models of $\sf ZF+DC+BP$ (where $\sf BP$ is the statement that every set of real numbers have the Baire property).

---

**See also:**

- [Vector Spaces and AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207990/vector-spaces-and-ac/)

Comment: I was waiting for you! Thanks. What can we say about classification?

Comment: I was just watching a movie, sorry it took so long! ;-) What do you mean by classification?

Comment: :) - Classification of all vector spaces with this property. I'm not good at that subject obviously so this question might be nonsense.

Comment: Ah. I don't think that this sort of thing exists. We know how to generate counterexamples, and we know to prove that certain counterexamples exist. But I don't think we have any idea what sort of wild creatures are out there.

Answer (score 1):

I think for any field $F$, the $F$-vector space $F^{\mathbb{N}}$ of all sequences over $F$ provides a suitable example. (Note that the unit vectors only generate the subspace consisting of all vectors with finitely many non-zero entries.)

Comment: Okay, can you classify all vector spaces with this property?

Comment: @Dahlersit: This sounds like a new and much harder question.

Comment: Yes, can I edit/change my question? Is this appropriate?

Comment: Just because we can't describe the basis doesn't mean it doesn't exist! For this particular example, if the axiom of choice holds up to a sufficiently large cardinal, then $F^{\mathbb{N}}$ would have a basis. But the axiom of choice could still fail higher up.

Comment: @Dahlersit: No, you shouldn't change your question in something different. Post a new one instead.

Comment: @ZhenLin: You are right. The question I had in mind was more like this one: Find a vector space $V$ such that the statement "$V$ does not have a base" is consistent with ZF.