# How $(\mathbb R,+)$ is a decomposible group?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

We know that $(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\},.)$ is decomposible as it can be expressed as internal direct product of $\mathbb R^{+}$ and $\{-1,1\}$. I have also found somewhere that $(\mathbb R,+)$ is decomposible. Can anyone explain how to show it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah...sorry...I am changing it.

Answer (score 6):

We can see $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ (so using rationals as scalars). This has a base (using the axiom of choice, there is no explicit description for such a base!) $B = \{x_i : i \in I \}$, that we can split in to linearly independent subsets, say $B_1 = \{x_i: i \in I_1 \}$ and $B_2 = \{x_i: i \in I_2\}$. Then $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is a direct sum of the span of $B_1$ and the span of $B_2$.

Comment: What are $I_1$ and $I_2$?

Comment: Any decomposition of $I$, the index set for the base

Comment: Maybe it is more clear if you mention that $B_1$ and $B_2$ should be disjoint. I wonder if there is any solution that would avoid the axiom of choice..

Comment: @spin That's part of decomposition (for me). AC might be unavoidable, I'm not sure.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Some amount of choice is necessary; ZF alone is not sufficient to prove that such a basis exists. (Both the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587025/whats-an-example-of-a-vector-space-that-doesnt-have-a-basis-if-we-dont-accept) mention the fact; I can't seem to find a good reference in literature for it though, but everyone seems to know it)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Does the decomposition alone imply the existence of a basis? I don't think so. Hence my doubt. I know for sure that we cannot prove the existence of a base for the reals over the rationals without some choice (it's in the book Consequences of the Axiom of Choice). But the decomposition of the reals in 2 summands is probably weaker still.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think choice still is needed. To sketch a proof: Choose some $x\in B_1$ greater than $0$. Now, consider the sets $S_n=(B_1\cap [nx,(n+2)x)) + (B_2\cap (-nx,(1-n)x])$. We have that $[x,2x)\subseteq \bigcup S_n \subseteq [0,2x)$ so the measure of the union of finite and positive. However, I think one can translate $S_n$ to coincide with $S_m$ except for an arbitrarily small difference. Thus, they have the same measure - but this means $S_n$ is not measurable - but in ZF, it is consistent that no such sets exists.