# Computability of Vector Representations without Inner Products.

Tags: linear-algebra, computability, change-of-basis, hamel-basis

Assume you have a separable inner product space $V$ with **orthonormal basis** $B=(e_a)_{a∈A}$ and an element $v∈V$. Then there is a simple algorithm to compute the representation of $V$ with respect to $B$: since $|v⟩ = ∑_{a∈A}⟨eₐ∣v⟩|eₐ⟩$ we simply need to do:

```
def coeff(v, B):
   for eₐ in B:
       yield inner(v, eₐ)
```

This allows us to do a peculiar thing: compute the representation of $v$ with respect to $B$, **in a manner agnostic of the representation of $v$**, using only inner product space operations. It seems to me the same is **not** possible in general vector spaces, but I am struggling to coming up with an ansatz to prove it; so here is my question.

---

Assume $V$ is a Vector space without any additional norm/inner product structure, $v∈V$ and $B=(e_a)_{a∈A}$ is a **Hamel basis**.

- Is there an algorithm, **using only vector space operations**, that produces the representation of $v$ with respect to $B$?
- What about the finite dimensional case?

**NOTE:** We may assume that $v$ is given in some other basis $B'$, but we **may not assume that the representation of the basis vectors of $B'$ is known in terms of $B$**. Otherwise, this would be a straightforward application of [change of basis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Change_of_basis), and miss the point about trying to do it in a manner agnostic to the representation of $v$.

---

For a vector space $V$ over field $K$ we shall allow the field operations $+ₖ$, $⋅ₖ$, $-ₖ$, ${()^{-1}}ₖ$, the vector operations $+ᵥ$, $-ᵥ$, the scalar product $⋅$, as well as equality checks $=ₖ, =ᵥ$.

**Observations:**

- In the case of a finite dimensional VS over a finite field, such an algorithm exists in the form of simple brute-force search.
- Possibly related: [Vector space bases without axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461436/vector-space-bases-without-axiom-of-choice)

Comment: There's two isomorphic vector spaces $(V, B)$ and $(V, B')$. Requiring that we don't know the representation of $B$ in $B'$ makes me think vector space operations won't really work, since the operations are different in $(V, B)$ than in $(V, B')$, and we are not given a way of relating them, like a linear transformation.  I suppose in the finite dimensional case, one could try to optimize $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ such that $|\vec{v} - a_1 e_1 + \cdots + a_n e_n|$ is at a minimum.  But, the finite dimensional case always has an inner product for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.  Just my thoughts.

Comment: @J126 The finite dimensional case need not have an inner product, e.g. if $K$ is a finite field. The idea of minimizing the residual $v-λeₐ$ is intuitive, however, $|\vec{v} - a_1 e_1 + \cdots + a_n e_n|$ is undefined without assuming a norm structure. But overall, I think the idea is right that without an inner product there seems to be no automatism for relating $B$ to $B'$, the question is how to prove it.

Comment: My comment about finite dimensional vector spaces specified that it was over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, where there is always an inner product.  As above, if you are giving no data to relate $B$ to $B'$, how can one expect to compute a change in coefficients?

Comment: @J126 How do you construct inner product for a general vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? The only construction I am aware of uses a basis and has the same problem of finding coordinates with respect to the basis.