# Dimension Theorem Corollary

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces with $\dim V = \dim W$. If $T : V → W$ is
linear then $T$ is one-to-one if and only if $T$ is onto. 
But this is true only when the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are finite.
For instance I came across the example $T : P(R)\to P(R)$ such that $T(f(x))=f'(x)$. Here T is onto but not one-one.
Can we generalize the case for infinite dimensions too in any way?

Comment: This cannot be generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that without the [axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice), we can't speak about the dimension of a vector space in general, because [there would be vector spaces without a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/207992/26369)! For the rest of this post, I will be assuming the axiom of choice without comment.

---

Every vector space has a dimension (the only allowed size for a basis) which is either a natural number or an [infinite cardinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number). For brevity, I will use $n$ for $\dim V$.

There are a few important theorems at play here:

### Theorem 1: Adding $0$

> Suppose that $n=x+y$ for cardinal numbers $n$, $x$, and $y$. Then if $x=0$, $y=n$. (This could be written more simply as $0+n=n$, or similar.)

### Theorem 2: Subtracting $n$

> Suppose that $n=x+y$ for cardinal numbers $n$, $x$, and $y$, with $n$ finite. Then if $y=n$, $x=0$.

This theorem **fails** if $n$ is infinite, and it can do so in a very concrete way. If you remove one element from an infinite set of size $n$, then you still have an infinite set of size $n$ left over.

### Theorem 3: A theorem about dimension

> If $n$ is finite, then the only $n$-dimensional subspace of $V$ is $V$ itself.

**Proof:** Essentially, a linearly independent set is either already a basis for $V$, or can be extended by choosing independent vectors until you reach a basis for $V$. Extending set of $n$ vectors would give you at least $n+1\ne n$ vectors (see Theorem 2) which is too many; a basis for the subspace must be a basis for $V$.$\square$

This theorem **fails** if $n$ is infinite, for the same reason that Theorem 2 fails in that case. If you take a basis for $V$, and remove, say, finitely many vectors from it, then you have a basis for a proper subspace of $V$ that has the same dimension.

### Theorem 4: Rank-Nullity

> $n=\dim \ker T+\dim \mathrm{im}\,T$.

[The rank-nullity theorem still holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/752069/26369) even when we may be talking about infinite cardinals.

### Theorem 5: Your corollary part 1

> If $n$ is finite and $\dim W=n$, then for any linear $T:V\to W$, if $T$ is one-to-one then $T$ is onto.

**Proof:** If $T$ is one-to-one then $\dim \ker T=0$ so that $\dim \mathrm{im}\,T=n$ by theorem 1. By theorem 3 (here we use finiteness of $n$) this forces $T$ to be onto. $\square$

This reliance on finiteness is unavoidable. [right-shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Sequences) is one-to-one from a space of one-sided infinite sequences (or similar) to itself, but not onto. In general, if $n$ is infinite then a bijection from "a basis for $V$" to "all but one element of a basis for $W$" generates a linear map akin to right-shift. Thus, this **always has counterexamples** if $n$ is infinite.

### Theorem 6: Your corollary part 2

> If $n$ is finite and $\dim W=n$, then for any linear $T:V\to W$, if $T$ is onto then $T$ is one-to-one.

**Proof:** If $T$ is onto then $\dim \mathrm{im}\,T=n$. By theorem 2 (here we use the finiteness of $n$), $\dim \ker T=0$ so that $T$ is one-to-one. $\square$

This reliance on finiteness is unavoidable. The example in your question is onto but not one-to-one. Another common example is a [left-shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Sequences) operator. In general, if $n$ is infinite then a bijection from "all but one element of a basis for $V$" to "a basis for $W$" generates a linear map akin to left-shift if you send the remaining basis element of $V$ to $0_W$. Thus, this **always has counterexamples** if $n$ is infinite.

---

In conclusion, both halves of the corollary you mention have counterexamples no matter how nice spaces you pick $V$ and $W$ to be, and this ultimately boils down to the failure of theorem 2 in the infinite case. **No**, we cannot generalize.