# Proof of $\text{dim}(E)\leq\text{dim}(E^*)$ without using a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector space over a (not necessarily commutative) field $K$. How can we show that $\text{dim}(E)\leq\text{dim}(E^*)$ without using a basis?

My proof uses a basis. Let $(b_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $E$. We have a family $(b^*_i)_{i\in I}$ of elements of $E^*$ characterized by $\langle b_i,b^*_j\rangle=0$ for $i\ne j$ and $\langle b_i,b^*_i\rangle=0$. Clearly this family is free. Let $H$ be the subspace of $E^*$ generated by $(b^*_i)_{i\in I}$. Then
$$\text{dim}(E)=|I|=\dim(H)\leq\dim(E^*).$$

Is there a way to prove this without using a basis?

Comment: Do you have a definition of dimension at hand that does *not* use bases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a result [due to Blass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207990/vector-spaces-and-ac) that "every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). Without AC this result is not necessarily true; in fact it's consistent with ZF that there exist infinite-dimensional vector spaces $E$ such that $E^{\ast} = 0$. See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49388/is-the-non-triviality-of-the-algebraic-dual-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-sp) for some details, giving the example of $E = \mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Of course without bases / AC we have the further problem that it's no longer even clear what $\dim E$ means. We could take it to mean either the smallest size of a generating subset or the largest size of a linearly independent subset and it's no longer clear that these coincide. But in any case it's clear that with either of these definitions $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$ is infinite (and with a little effort uncountable; this, requires explicitly constructing an uncountable linearly independent subset which is done [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets)), whereas it's consistent that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ which certainly has dimension $0$.

Comment: Nice answer. For a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, see also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/80905).