# Can we derive a norm and an inner product from a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Given an inner product on a vector space, I can always define a norm and a metric (and a topology using that metric). Is the converse true? That is, given a metric on a vector space, can I define an inner product with it? And what about a metric space that is not a vector space?

Comment: A norm is only meaningful for a vector space because we need an internal addition in $\|u+v\| \le \|u\| +\|v\| $ and an external multiplication for $\| \lambda . u\|=| \lambda| \| u\|$

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If not (and it doesn't sound like one to me), then it doesn't deserve the adverse comments and downvotes.

Comment: Some related posts on this site: [An example of a norm which can't be generated by an inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/159766) (and a few other [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inner-products+normed-spaces+examples-counterexamples)) and [Not every metric is induced from a norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166380) (again, you can check [other questions with similar tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces+normed-spaces+examples-counterexamples)).

Comment: As Jean Marie points out, it makes sense to speak of a metric on any given set. However, to make sense of a *norm*, we need a vector space structure (and moreover, the underlying field must be either the real numbers or the complex numbers).

Answer (score 11):

Let $k$ denote the field of real numbers, or the field of complex numbers. Given a vector space $V$ over $k$, it is always possible define a metric on $V$ (say the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space#Definitions)), or a norm on $V$ ([by choosing a Hamel basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62778/does-every-mathbbr-mathbbc-vector-space-have-a-norm)). However, if the norm you define has no relation to the metric you define, then there is no point in studying them simultaneously.

Thus, we should restrict our attention to metrics $d$ that are *induced* by a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, in the sense that $d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert$ for all $x,y\in V$. This way, the metric and norm “interact” with each other. A metric induced by a norm has two special properties:

- **Translation invariance:** $d(x+c,y+c)=d(x,y)$ for all $c,x,y\in V$.
- **Absolute homogeneity:** $d(\lambda x,\lambda y)=|\lambda|d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in V$ and $\lambda\in k$.

Your question becomes: given a vector space $V$ over $k$ and a metric $d$ on $V$, must there be a norm on $V$ which induces $d$? The answer is negative. Consider, for instance, the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ (with the usual vector space operations). The discrete metric on $\mathbb R^3$ is not absolutely homogeneous, and hence is not induced by a norm. On the other hand, we do have a positive result: if a metric $d$ on $V$ is translation invariant and absolutely homogeneous, then it is induced by the norm $x\mapsto \lVert x\rVert=d(x,0)$.

A similar story occurs with inner product spaces. A norm induced by an inner product satisfies a special property, namely the parallelogram law $2\lVert x\rVert+2\lVert y\rVert=\lVert x+y\rVert^2-\lVert x-y\rVert^2$. Not every norm satisfies this, hence not every norm is induced by an inner product. But if a norm *does* satisfy the parallelogram law, then it is induced by an inner product (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law/43848#43848) for a proof).